# Dynamically change <option> list for <form:select> in spring MVC

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a working spring form which is submitted with the help of a HTML submit button and the path variable are all picked up respectively. I now have to introduce two drop downs inside that form - **Type** and **Sub Type**. I have a custom object for list items that contain the text n values and i would to use them for my new lists. The Type list is pretty straightforward but the Sub Type list will show some specific options that will depend upon the selection in **Type** list. So i have some types and some sub types for each type. I pass them to my JSP via model attributes as below.

```
model.addAttribute("types", typeList);

model.addAttribute("subType1", subTypeList1);

model.addAttribute("subType2", subTypeList2);

model.addAttribute("subType3", subTypeList3);

model.addAttribute("subType4", subTypeList4);

model.addAttribute("subType5", subTypeList5);
```

And in my JSP

```
<form:select path="type" 
id="type" itemValue="${bean.type}">
<c:forEach var="record" items="${typeList}" varStatus="status">
<form:option value="${record.val}" label="${record.text}" />
</c:forEach></form:select>

<form:select path="subType" 
    id="subType" itemValue="${bean.subType}">
    </form:select>
```

Now the problem i am facing is that i wish to populate subType list based upon current selection in type list. For this i am creating hidden options in my JSP like this.

```
 <div id="generalSubType">
<c:forEach items="subtypeList1" var="record">
<option value="${record.val}">${record.text}</option>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

Whenever a type is selected in types list, i swap the content in subtype list with respective div contents.

So i am wondering what can be a standard way to use multiple option lists to get value inside a spring form select. I know about the way where i populate my bean via javascript and then submit it with from there, but i do not wish to change my current form to that.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use DWR here.
Create a javascript function and pass the "${record.val}" to that method on change of "generalSubType". Based on the record value you can populate "type" dropdown box with new list or map.

Refer this for help: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html